# Search does not clear filter

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to do a search on a text field (mongodb). The Search criteria / filter on the collection can be any substring of the sting in the field. I save the filter (input) in a session variable. The filter seems to work the first time after the Sessionvariable is null. 
After the first search I get no result when I enter a new (extisting!) value. In case I clear the filter, hit enter and than reenter the filter I get the result.
I assume that my code is suboptimal. Can someone please review and maybe make a suggestion?

Here is what I have:

html:

```
<input class="medinput" maxlength="80" type="text" name="nameSearchBar" id="nameSearchBar"  value="{{searchText}}">
```

javascript:

```
Session.setDefault('searchText', null);

Template.questions.helpers({
    questions:function(){
        if ((Session.get('searchText') === null) || (Session.get('searchText') === '')) {
        Session.get('searchText',null);
        return Questions.find({archived:{$ne:true}});
    } else {
        var searchText = Session.get('searchText');
        Session.get('searchText',null);
        return Questions.find( { $and: [ { archived: { $ne: true } }, {note:{$regex: (".*"+searchText+".*") } } ] } )
    }
    },
    searchText:function(){
        return Session.get('searchText');
    }
})


Template.questions.events({
"change #nameSearchBar":function(event){;
        searchText = event.target.value;
        Session.set('searchText', searchText);
    }
})
```

Questions:

- why do I need to first "enter" an empty string to get a valid result
- is this a good procedure? Doesn't hitting enter works against the reactive 
  approach? I think after enter the complete page is resent ??
- Would it be better to check "keyup" for ASCII 27 and 13?
- it seems to me that the regex works, are there any concerns? I like to find any substring of the typed in filter, also when the filter has a whitespace.
- this is a full text search do I need to set something up on the mongodb side?
- Open Question: are the already prebuild implementiations - I do not need to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my interpretation, or how I would possibly have built this:

```
Template.questions.helpers({
    questions:function(){
        var searchText = Session.get('search-text');
        if(searchText && searchText != '') {
            return Questions.find({$and: [{archived: {$ne: true}}, {note:{$regex: (".*"+searchText+".*")}}]});
        } else {
            return Questions.find({archived: {$ne: true}});
        }
    }
});

Template.questions.events({
    "keyup #nameSearchBar": _.throttle(function(event){
        searchText = event.target.value;
        Session.set('searchText', searchText);
    }), 500)
});
```

To me it doesn't seem necessary to set a default, or to call `Session.get('search-text', null)`. Also you'll see how my code is a bit more concise. `keyup` is probably more effective as an event here too.

N.B. The `_.throttle` is an underscore.js function which will limit changing the Session variable to only every 500ms rather than constantly. This helps save unnecessary server load.

Two pre-built packages that are popular amongst Meteor developers are worth looking into: [Easy Search](https://atmospherejs.com/matteodem/easy-search) or [Search Source](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/search-source)

Answer (score 0):

I copied a generally working example for a search on a single text field.

@Ian: Thanks for the suggestion! I took the toggle part, I found that you can not leave the session variable as is, even it gets over written, it must evaluated before. So it has to be set back with NULL.

```
Session.setDefault('searchText', null);

Template.questions.helpers({
questions:function(){
    if ((Session.get('searchText') === null) || (Session.get('searchText') === '')) {
            return Questions.find({archived:{$ne:true}});
        } else {
            var searchText = Session.get('searchText');
            return Questions.find( { $and: [ { archived: { $ne: true } }, {note:{$regex: (".*"+searchText+".*") } } ] } )
        }
    },
    searchText:function(){
        return Session.get('searchText');
    }
})
Template.questions.events({
    'keyup #nameSearchBar': _.throttle(function(event){;
        Session.set('searchText',null);
        searchText = event.target.value;
        Session.set('searchText', searchText);
    },500)
})
```